# Change React build path post application build

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

The project structure that we have is:

```
 | - - - - - - myproject-service
 |              | - - - src
 |                       | - - - main
 |                       | - - - resources
 |                               | - - - static
 | - - - - - - myproject-ui
                | - - - build
```

When we build the UI project the build folder is created in the project. But we want to copy the build folder to `mypoject-service/src/main/resources/static/`

How do we achieve that during the build phase?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `create-react-app` you should have a `paths.js` file in the config folder.
change the

```
appBuild: resolveApp('build'),
```

in `module.exports` section to your path which in your case will probably be:

```
appBuild: resolveApp('../myproject-service/src/main/static')
```